# adding a image to access database in C#

Tags: c#

sir can you explain me how add image to access database through the C# gui application. for an example we have one gui application.in that there is a picture box and add button.once we click add, it should ask the location of picture. once we select the the photo. then it should be stored in access database. i am having a big problem in that please help me.

Comment: What is your approach so far. With what specific part of your assignment do you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

Manoj you can store images in access as an `OLE field`

a detail [tutorial](http://www.jamiessoftware.tk/articles/handlingimages.html)